# elasticsearch update gives unknown field error

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch

I am using the Elasticsearch's Typescript client, and when I try to update a document:

```
import { RequestParams } from '@elastic/elasticsearch'      
const updateParam: RequestParams.Update = {
      id: '111',
      index: 'myIndex',
      body: {email: 'aaa@aa.ca'},
}
return elasticsearchClient.update(updateParam)
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                "reason": "[1:2] [UpdateRequest] unknown field [id], parser not found"
            }
        ],
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[1:2] [UpdateRequest] unknown field [id], parser not found"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

But according to the document here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_update, `id` is a field in the input

What's wrong with my request param?

Comment: can you also post your index mappings?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Turned out, the RequestParams.Update should looke like this:

```
const updateParam: RequestParams.Update = {
      id: '111',
      index: 'myIndex',
      body: {doc:{email: 'aaa@aa.ca'}},
}
```

So the actual data will need to be wrapped in "doc" field. I will make a PR to the lib on github... there is no way people can just figure it out by just the documentation.

Comment: Saved a day. May be should be specify doc field as required in RequestParams.Update interface's body? So we can figure it out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know whether Elasticsearch has updated the documentation after this, but you can see an example https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.x/update_examples.html `await client.update({
    index: 'game-of-thrones',
    id: '1',
    body: {
      doc: {
        isAlive: false
      }
    }
  })`

Comment: Had the same issue with OpenSearch and Python lib. Used:
`search_client.update(index=index_name, id=doc_id, body={"doc": body}, refresh=True)`

Answer (score 7):

Send the body in "doc" key to resolve this problem. I am using typescript along with Elasticsearch 7.8. Earlier it was 6.7 version where found no issues but started getting it after migration to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

This 'id' is not a field in your document content.It just like 'index' and 'type'.You can't change index's name and type when you update one document,so you can't change one document's id.It is the identification of a document.But if you have a field named 'id',you can update like that.

Comment: How does ES know which document to update if I do not provide an `id`?

Comment: The id parameter on the top level object that you pass as parameter to the update call is what you can see on the Elasticsearch responses as _id. You might have an id property in your document or not. @jamesdeath123. The real issue on the initial question is that the document object to be updated was not wrapped on the body parameter inside the doc property

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in ElasticSearch `7.17` [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-update.html#_update_part_of_a_document) to wrap the body in the `doc` key to perform partial updates

Comment: Thanks for the update. Finally! Tooke them 2+ years.